# Is there a way to create a document with a specific filename in flutter firebase

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I need a way in which to create a firebase document with a specific name.

`Firestore.instance.collection("fruit").add(filename = "banna")/// Semi pseudo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this instead `Firestore.instance.collection("fruit").document("banana"). setData({taste:"yummy"});`